# Alpine.js + Laravel flash message disappears instantly

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, alpine.js

I coded a flash message for successful listing that lasts 3 seconds after a redirect but as soon as redirect it disappears. I can see a glimpse of it, like 10 milliseconds. Here is the code:

```
@if(session()->has("message"))
    <div x-data="{show: true" x-init="setTimeout(() => show = false, 3000)" x-show="show">
        <p>
            {{session("message")}}
        </p>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: missing curly brace after show:true;

Answer (score 1):

You can use `x-effect` instead of `x-init` because you can't access show variable inside the setTimeout

```html
@if(session()->has("message"))
    <div x-data="{show: true}" x-effect="setTimeout(() => show = false, 3000)" x-show="show">
        <p>
            {{session("message")}}
        </p>
    </div>
@endif
```

For more information about x-effect https://alpinejs.dev/directives/effect